# c++ multi threading - lock one pointer assignment?

Tags: multithreading

I have a method as below

```
SomeStruct* abc;

void NullABC()
{
    abc = NULL;
}
```

This is just example and not very interesting.
Many thread could call this method at the same time.
Do I need to lock "abc = NULL" line?
I think it is just pointer so it could be done in one shot and there isn't really need for it but just wanted to make sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the platform on which you are running.  On many platforms, as long as `abc` is correctly aligned, the write will be atomic.

However, if your platform does not have such a guarantee, you need to synchronize access to the variable, using a lock, an atomic variable, or an interlocked operation.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need a lock, at least not on x86. A memory barrier is required in may real world situations though, and locking is one way to get this (the other would be an [explicit barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684208%28VS.85%29.aspx)). You may also consider using an interlocked operation, like VisualC's [InterlockedExchangePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you need access to the original pointer. There are equivalent intrinsics supported by most compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If no other threads are ever using abc for any other purpose, then the code as shown is fine... but of course it's a bit silly to have a pointer that never gets used except to set it to NULL.

If there is some other code somewhere that does something like this, OTOH:

```
if (abc != NULL)
{
   abc->DoSomething();
}
```

Then in this case both the code that uses the abc pointer (above) and the code that changes it (that you posted) needed to lock a mutex before accessing (abc).  Otherwise the code above risks crashing if the value of abc gets set to NULL after the if statement but before the DoSomething() call.

A borderline case would be if the other code does this:

```
SomeStruct * my_abc = abc;
if (my_abc != NULL)
{
   my_abc->DoSomething();
}
```

That will probably work, because at the time the abc pointer's value is copied over to my_abc, the value of abc is either NULL or it isn't... and my_abc is a local variable, so other thread's won't be able to change it before DoSomething() is called.  The above could theoretically break on some platforms where copying of pointers isn't atomic though (in which case my_abc might end up being an invalid pointer, with have of abc's bits and half NULL bits)... but common/PC hardware will copy pointers atomically, so it shouldn't be an issue there.  It might be worthwhile to use a Mutex anyway just to for paranoia's sake though.